# Limit lines in textarea in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, textarea

This script below works BUT if I type longer word in the last line it will be extended to additional line and the script will accept that? How to make sure that only 7 lines are accepted in any possible ways?

```
$lines = array_slice(explode("\n", trim( $_POST['description'])), 0, 7); // max 7 lines

foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $lines[$key] = substr(trim($value), 0, 200); // max 200 chars
}

$insert['teams_descr'] = implode("\n", $lines);
                $this->db->update( 'teams', $insert, array( 'teams_id' => $this->user->leader_team_id() ) );
```

Comment: [You posted this already](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25939035/) - Plus I quote from your other question - *"Actually it does work BUT if I type bigger sentence like one word..."* - If you want to limit text, use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and not `trim()`. This should be closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: If a word makes the sentence wrap it is not really a new line.

Comment: even if you are writing long word in the last, it may seem you in next line but logically it is not as each line separated using enter (\n).

Comment: yeah logically it isn't but I am looking for a method to cut it off and avoid this new line by writing bigger word or just doing it on purpose. is there any way for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Put a constraint in *javascript* to not allow more than 7 lines by writing a function and calling it via the onChange attr of the textarea. Then in php check the number of newline chars. It should then never exceed 7 unless someone is cheating or your js code doesn't work.

Per your requirements (where lines can't exceed a specified number of characters) your js function will have to take into account both actual returns and number of characters, so it will have to insert a real return character after certain number of characters, but will have to do so in such a way as to not break up words in the middle. So when you hit the max number of chars for a line, you'll have to go back to the previous whitespace and insert a return char there.  Something like that. But you might also want it to go ahead and break up the text even when there's no whitespace if it seems the text doesn't contain actual words. Since only you understand your requirements fully, only you can code this. Even any example code would be worthless to you.